# How to play audio without extension

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I use SoundIt to stream data on my network.
Soundit exports the sound local using localhost:port
I then use ngrok to make a tunnel to my localhosts port and i get an address
http://xxx.ngrok.io

Is there a way to add to my site only the audio from ngrok's url?

I tried iframe ,object data , embed src
But all these loads the page and makes clients browser using 50% of cpu.
Is it possible to play only the audio from the url?
Thank you

Comment: <audio preload="auto" src="https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/43e7efa8214783c2af2cb32edbb94b7c836fc4b2?cid=null"></audio>' I copy this from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829572/is-there-a-way-to-play-audio-on-a-mobile-browser-with-only-a-src-url

Comment: I tried it. I added to my site on body '<audio preload="auto" src="https://xxx.eu.ngrok.io"></audio>' but does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audio tag

```
<audio controls>

  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

Then you can use Javascript to start playing and pausing etc.

Comment: I tried that, but my url dont have extension (.mp3) and it dosnt work

Comment: Check this thread out, might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254808/specify-that-src-in-audio-is-a-mp3-file-without-mp3-extension

Comment: this might also be helpful https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/html5-canvas/9781449308032/ch07s04.html

Comment: I have visited these sites, but i am new on html.and i dont know how to add all these to my site.

Comment: if you post your code and an a link to an audio file maybe I can show you.